# Change functionality of Component Form View based on linked component

Tags: 2011, event-system, tom.net

Note: I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

I have created a schema with a multi-value embedded schema. The embedded schema contains 2 fields:

component - a component link (any schema allowed)
component_template - a list of allowed component templates for the selected component

[image: Wrapper component fields]

What I want to do is use the selected component to determine the allowed component templates and expose a list of allowed templates for selection as a drop-down list for component_template.

This replicates the functionality of a component presentation list on a page but within a component.

Comment: I would recommend investigating Experience Manager and the concept of "Content Type". Won't solve your question, but may change your approach.

Comment: This Content Injection approach approach is definitely familiar but I typically get feedback that it's both flexible yet confusing to new Tridion users. Miguel Miguelez describes the [pros/cons and additional ways to "inject" CPs even in rich text](http://www.tridionworld.com/articles/understanding_content_injection.aspx). I add some perspective on [when Content Injection seems to work best](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/04/tame-content-injection-monster.html) in a follow-up post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you seek cannot be accomplished using the event system. If you want to change functionality based on the linked component, you should look into `GUI Extensions` or maybe you can work with a `Custom URL`. Although I'm not sure the latter is able to take other fields into account.

Also by default Tridion is not able to show a dropdown of component templates, so you really need a GUI Extension. Maybe you should look at your problem again and try to figure out a different approach!

**WAS:** Tridion provided a [matrix](https://sdltridionworld.com/images/event_matrix_tcm89-18738.pdf) to all available events in Tridion 2011+ compared to the old VB6 event system.

Comment: Hi MrSnowflake,

Thanks for your response. Should I be using 'OnComponentResolvePre' for my example then? If so, do you know where I should look for resources on creating a custom resolver?

Comment: Custom resolvers are pretty simple to create - if you google for "Tridion Custom Resolver" you'll find quite a few examples and blog posts

Comment: Bart Koopman explained you do have access to the full collection of fields (http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2099/46). In terms of GUI Extension, his [Item Selector extension](http://www.tridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) would be worth looking into. We can even contribute to the [open source project](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/#svn%2FItem%20Selector%2Ftrunk) for it--"template selection based on X" sounds like a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that GUI Extensions is what I need to implement for this example as it can't be achieved with the Event System.